# Reading from a file inside a VS solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, file

I have an xml file that I want to include along with my program as a template.  I would prefer that it be bundled with the .exe when the project is completed.

Is this possible?

If so, how should I reference it in the code?  I would assume that referencing "myXML.xml" won't work because, if it is included, the file no longer exists as a standalone object.

An alternative idea is to copy/paste the contents into string, but that seems like a bad idea in so many ways. (It's 900 lines.)

Ideas?

Thank you.

The real motivation behind this is I really prefer standalone executables rather than making the user go through the installation process.  Additionally there's the extra benefit that they're less likely to f- it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple to do, you can store files in any .NET assembly as "Embedded Resources", which can be then accessed at runtime.

See the Microsoft article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) for a detailed rundown on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is resource files, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx